# ConstraintLayout: EditText.requestFocus() is not working normally when it is added in Group

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack

`EditText.requestFocus()` is not working normally when it is added in a Group,

I removed Group and works fine.

this is not working: focus is still on `firstField`, (focus is on `secondField` only on second click)

```
someLayout.setOnClickListener {
    grSomething.visibility = Group.VISIBLE
    secondField.requestFocus()
}

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/secondField"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00f"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstField"/>

<android.support.constraint.Group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grSomething"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="secondField"/>
```

and this is working: focus is on `secondField`

```
someLayout.setOnClickListener {
    secondField.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    secondField.requestFocus()
}

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/secondField"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstField"/>
```

Comment: Please, share some code.

Comment: @grabarz121 Please, see updated question

Comment: But call this listener second time will pass focus with no problem. I think focus request may be call too fast, when change visibility of view is not fully end. What I tried, it's call requestfocus line inside `Handler.postDelayed()` method with little time period like 1-100ms. Another way is to listen on layout state changes. calling `.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` e.q. on edittext or group. When you'll change visibility, state of layout will change too, and you can call request focus there.

Comment: @grabarz121 Thanks for your answer, it's strange that group's visibility change has delay, and view's - not.